# Math to dynamically shift elements within a div for fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I’m working on a card game in JS. The player’s cards are dynamically displayed as elements inside a div of a set width. As cards are added to the player’s hand, I’m using `right: %` and `z-index` to shift all cards left and have them overlap each other, thereby making room to display more cards within the div (which is set to `white-space: nowrap` so content inside it won't break to a new line).

I’m using JS to calculate and set the percentage for the cards to shift left, based on each card’s original position and the total number of cards that need to be displayed.

The general plan is working, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to calculate a percentage that will work for any number of cards. Ideally, I'd like the cards to shift left just enough so that no matter how many there are they never extend outside the div but always fill it completely.

I thought the following would work:

```
function displayHand(cards) {
  for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var cardDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById(“playerHand”).appendChild(cardDiv);
    if(cards.length > 7) {
      cardDiv.setAttribute("style", "z-index: " + i + "; right: " 
        + (i * cards.length) * (0.04815 * cards.length) + "%");
    }
}
```

However, I seem to be getting this formula wrong: `(i * cards.length) * (0.04815 * cards.length)`. (Note that the 0.04815 number came from tinkering and trying to get the percentage right.)

By increasing the 0.04815 number I can make a small number of cards (i.e. 8-12) fit well but a larger number will be shifted much too close together, filling only a small portion of the div. If I decrease the number, 12 cards will overflow the div but a larger number will fit well inside it.

Comment: Check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The following formula works for any number of elements, shifting them over just enough to make room without ever over- or under-filling the container div: `i * (((cards.length - 7) * (0.1428 * 100)) / (cards.length - 1))`

Here `7` represents the original number of elements in the container, `0.1428` represents the width of the elements, and `-1` represents the first element, furthest to the left, which doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you don't need the first card to move. Your `cards.length` factor is too high.

Instead, you need only consider `cards.length-1`.

For instance, let's say I can fit in two cards exactly. To add a third card, I would need to move the cards left for a total of 1 card width by the time *two* cards (after the first) have been placed. That is, at 50% and 100%. Adding a fourth card would result in the cards being shifted at 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3. And so on.

So it should simply be a case of moving it by `i * (cards.length-1) * (card width here)`

Comment: I've made this change but I'm still having trouble. The width of each card is 12.8 percent of the container div, which itself is 65% percentage of the body width, so I tried `i * (cards.length - 1) * 0.128 + "%");` but the results are about the same.